# PHP MySQL Admin Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a Query to get the transaction per user, I am working my way on the queries, still learning, any assistance will be appreciated.

Below Query is getting what I need for another report, pretty much transactions per Day, working good:

```
SELECT
date_generator.date as the_date,
IFNULL(COUNT(transactions.transaction_id), 0) as count
from (
select DATE_ADD('2021-01-01', INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as date
from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub
where DATE_ADD('2021-01-01',INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-12'
) date_generator
left join transactions on DATE(edited) = date_generator.date
GROUP BY date
```

Generates Data:
the_date    count
2021-01-01  0 
2021-01-02  0 
2021-01-03  0 
2021-01-04  12 
2021-01-05  24 
2021-01-06  0 
2021-01-07  11
2021-01-08  0
2021-01-09  0
2021-01-10  5
2021-01-11  8
2021-01-12  3

My challenge, is that now I want the same data but per an specific username... in the same transaction table, I do have a column call username, which generates the transaction. I was playing with the Query but no luck, thanks for you assistance again.

Looking to Get... Where username = 'Test':
the_date    count
2021-01-01  0 
2021-01-02  0 
2021-01-03  0 
2021-01-04  1 
2021-01-05  0 
2021-01-06  0 
2021-01-07  1
2021-01-08  0
2021-01-09  0
2021-01-10  0
2021-01-11  1
2021-01-12  2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, and no answers... finally got what needed in another forum, in case someone else need this:

SELECT
date_generator.date as the_date, username,
IFNULL(COUNT(transactions.transaction_id), 0) as count
from (
select DATE_ADD('2021-01-01', INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as date
from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub
where DATE_ADD('2021-01-01',INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-12'
) date_generator
left join transactions on DATE(edited) = date_generator.date
AND username= 'Test'
GROUP BY date,  username